# document.evaluate not working in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, xpath, document.evaluate

I've got the following..

```
 var result = doc.evaluate("//input[@class=\"form_field_as as-input\"]", 
                           context, 
                           null, 
                           XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, 
                           null);
    for(var i = 0; i < result.snapshotLength; i++) {
    a[i] = result.snapshotItem(i);
}
return a;
```

The expression I'm evaluating is from an input. The code works fine in FireFox but when I test it on Chrome it doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong?

The input I'm evaluating is..

```
<input type="text" id="sharees" class="form_field_as">
```

Comment: when I'm just checking the javascript console in chrome with your code I get an error that says "doc" is not defined.

Comment: `doc` is just `document`

Comment: @Skizit: Apparently not?

Comment: sorry, I know that it's supposed to be document not doc. I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: context is not defined.` Maybe you could post more of the code here so that it will become more clear as to what these variables are supposed to be. ...ignore my last comment

Comment: @Stephen I don't really know what else to add. This is all within an iframe?

Comment: @jnpcl I'm unsure what you mean..

Comment: the `return` statement suggests that this code exists inside of a function. Maybe you could post the relevant parts of the whole function and a sample call to this function.

Comment: it's document.evaluate -- "`doc` is just `document` – Skizit"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator-evaluate

> `contextNode` **of type** `Node`
>   The
>   `context` is context node for the
>   evaluation of this XPath expression.
>   If the XPathEvaluator was obtained by
>   casting the `Document` then this must
>   be owned by the same document and must
>   be a `Document`, `Element`,
>   `Attribute`, `Text`, `CDATASection`,
>   `Comment`, `ProcessingInstruction`, or
>   `XPathNamespace` node. If the context
>   node is a `Text` or a `CDATASection`,
>   then the context is interpreted as the
>   whole logical text node as seen by
>   XPath, unless the node is empty in
>   which case it may not serve as the
>   XPath context.

So, your `context` must be some instance of these classes. I guess that you probably don't set this variable at all. You could also use `null` and the context would become the node from wich you are evaluating the expression.

Besides that, do note that `//input[@class='form_field_as as-input']` is an absolute expression and it will return the same result from any context (outside document context is not allowed when *"`XPathEvaluator` was obtained by casting the `Document`"* ).

Comment: Cool. I was just getting around to posting a similar answer with https://developer.mozilla.org/en/introduction_to_using_xpath_in_javascript as the resource. The examples on this page work fine in Chrome.